# Get Retrofit result as Json Object in Android

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I am using Retrofit API for communication. I want JSON Object to be stored directly in the Retrofit Result Bean. I tried the below process and it produced in null value. but while using postman the result is proper only.

The below is the output of the API

```
{
  "status": 101,
  "message": "Ok",
  "type": 1,
  "data": {
    "value": "adakdj4lkj43"
  }
}
```

The data field above keeps on changing as per the input in one case value on other case date this data depends on the type

below is my ResponseBean

```
public class ResponseBean {
    private int status = 0;
    private String message = "";
    private int type = 0;
    private JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
}
```

When performing the retrofit call I am getting this data as {} which means there is no data. Please help me to solve this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Which Retrofit version do you use? Could you paste you Retrofit config?

Comment: compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0' this is the retrofit I am using

Comment: Is this POST or GET ? Can you provide the url , if it is sensitive than , rename it before posting , Just need the url pattern

Comment: this is a local URL and this is POST Method. url is http://localhost:8080/API/Login/ the input is {"USERNAME":"UID", "PASS":"pass1234"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept you are trying to do is perfect. But the only thing here went wrong is using JSONObject in the Retrofit Bean. Retrofit is a library which convert the JSONObject to Bean Object. Better you try Object in stead of JSONObject. I think Retrofit does work on convert a part of JSONObject to Object. So try

```
            public class ResponseBean {
                            private int status = 0;
                            private String message = "";
                            private int type = 0;
                            private Object data = new Object();
            }
```

Instead of using this as DataType.

```
private JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using retrofit version 2 . Add the following dependency in your gradle file

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4'
```

Create an `interface` like this

```
public interface Api {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("Login")
    Call<ResponseBean> loginUser(@Field("uuid") String email, @Field("PASS") String password );
}
```

I have generated the model using [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Add the following classes

```
public class ResponseBean {

    private int status;
    private String message;
    private int type;
    private Data data;

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }


    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Data getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

And Data class

```
public class Data {

    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

Now in your `Activity`

```
 ResponseBean responseBean;
 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
     .baseUrl("https://localhost:8080/API/")
     .build();

 Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);

 Call<ResponseBean> call = api.loginUser("your_user_id","your_password");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBean>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBean> call, Response<ResponseBean> response) {
            responseBean = response.body();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBean> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Now you are storing jsonobject directly in responsebean . Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ResponseBean {
    private int status;
    private String message;
    private int type;
    private String data;

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public ResponseBean(JSONObject object){
        try {
            setStatus(object.getInt("status"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            setStatus(0);
        }

        try {
            setMessage(object.getString("status"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            setMessage("");
        }

        try {
            setType(object.getInt("type"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            setType(0);
        }

        try {
            setData(object.getString("data"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            setData("");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        try {
            object.put("status", getStatus());
            object.put("message", getMessage());
            object.put("type", getType());
            object.put("data", getData());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return object.toString();
    }
}
```

To add data

```
try {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject("yourData");
        ResponseBean responseBean = new ResponseBean(object);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

To get data

```
responseBean.getMessage();
```

Comment: I want to extract the value of the data as a jsonobject for other fields retrofit is doing it job perfectly.

Comment: responseBean.toString();

Comment: That dosent work i want to get the complete data as jsonobject. Say  {"value": "adakdj4lkj43"} i want in that json object so that i can convert the same to object with gson on loking at the type.

Answer (score 0):

Since Json is what you want at the end, you can try this:

```
public class ResponseBean {
    private int status = 0;
    private String message = "";
    private int type = 0;
    private ValueObject data;
}

public class ValueObject {
   private String value;
}
```

After adding getters and setters, you can do:

```
ResponseBeam rBeam = //Retrofit response here.
JsonObject requiredJsonObject = new JsonObject();
requiredJsonObject.put("value", rBeam.getData().getValue());

Log.d(TAG, requiredJsonObject);
```

Check your log for out as you required.

Comment: Bro the main reason i am trying to take this as a json object is because the data comes different on different cases in one case value and on another date on another message if i use the method you gave i have to write at least 6 classes. But method i am trying will complete the same in 4 classes. I have mentioned only 3 but i have 25 similar APIs i have to handel all

Comment: I did not observe that value changes, so gave it this way.